# How to create automatic parking bays

Tags: qgis

I have to draw all the car park spaces for several streets, I am asking for some advise, how is the best way to draw all those car park spaces? and (of 5 meters) applying some restrictions (Ej. like double yellow line). I am using QGIS and I am not going to have pre-made lines or anything, all just from base maps. (the bay should be 5 meteres each with some areas with the restrictions mentioned before).

Comment: I have no idea, but you may want to add the municipality/state/country  because there could be existing symbology that matches what's usually used.

Comment: are all parking spaces uniformal?

Comment: Thanks mkennedy  I will check it!The parkings are withing areas, there are areas where you cant park but the usual park size is 5 meters, so i i can divide my vector every 5 meters and then put the restrictions afterwards would be awesome.

Comment: Are the park spaces existent and you want to draw from aerial view or is this a planning project?

Comment: I want an aerial view MarHoff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well still not sure i exactly got you point but here is a process that might work:

1. For each street segment draw a polygon along the sidewalk that materialize the theoretical park space of the street. If possible draw by snapping an existing sidewalk polygon.

[image]

2. Use the "Split feature" tool to follow existing park space using your imagery and your field knowledge. Doing this will ensure that each parking polygon will stay topologically correct between each others.

[image]

3. Remove resulting polygons that are not corrects according to your rules

[image]

I might actually be totally wrong on your intend because maybe your country and mine don't define car park space in the same manner. If this is the case please provide some visual clues to refine your question.

Comment: I think that method is so far the only way to do it. Unlikely for myself there is not a open data for that. Just a quick question, I presumed that those polygons are individually ID's? I asking that because after i will apply all those restrictions. Is a great example thanks for your time MarHoff!

Comment: I've done this on a scratch layer but should I do that in production I would spend some time carefully thinking about the attributes columns I must have in the end. Every time you split a polygon a new ID will be generated but all attributes field will be copied to each splited polygon. Thus you can save yourself a lot of time if all space of a street have same attribute by filling them before splitting. After the slit you will always be able to edit each individual splited feature.

Comment: Also if you are new to QGIS please take time to learn how editing sessions work to save yourself a lot of trouble. For example how to undo recents change and why you cant undo after you saved your edit. And as with every unfortunately boring manual task, put in place a solid backup strategy! Good luck ;)

Comment: Sorry to add more info but I have another question, what happen if it is a line rather than the polygon, because I do no think I would manage one satellite map

Comment: This will work pretty much the same way but you now have a new problem, cause the real world object (area) won't fit the way you store the information (line). I might suggest to look at the way OpenStreetMap project handled theses problems http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:parking:lane but this might start to be pretty straightforward. Because another option for your project could be to input all your information into OpenStreetMap.org and that will make you work even more profitable and Open to the world. But you then have to make other compromises. It all depend on your goal and skills.